# Hibernate DB2 revoke STATEMENTs for User

Tags: hibernate, db2

I have DB2 databases persisted with Hibernate. 
I'd like to revoke DROP TABLE permissions for all TABLES in all databases for a concrete "user". So the ordinary "user" cannot DROP TABLES in any DB2 database. 
I have also mySQL databases, but I do not care abot doing DROP STATEMENT in them.

Is there any possibility to do it via tag in components.xml (hibernate) or does it have to be done directly on DB2? (and how? - What sort of sql script would revoke DROP STATEMENT for a concrete user on all schemes of ALL DB2s? 
To revoke CREATE STAT I've found this:

```
REVOKE CREATETAB ON DATABASE DB1 FROM USER1 BY ALL;
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000981.htm

...but what kind of STAT does revoke DROP TABLEs?)

=> components.xml:

```
...

<!-- 1st databse -->
<key>hibernate.connection.driver_class</key><value>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</value>
<key>hibernate.connection.username</key><value>user</value>
<key>hibernate.connection.password</key><value>password</value>
<key>hibernate.connection.url</key><value>jdbc:db2://server:50000/DATABASE1</value>
<key>hibernate.dialect</key><value>org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect</value>
<key>hibernate.default_schema</key><value>SCHEMA_NAME</value>

<!-- 2nd databse -->
<key>hibernate.connection.driver_class</key><value>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</value>
<key>hibernate.connection.username</key><value>user</value>
<key>hibernate.connection.password</key><value>password</value>
<key>hibernate.connection.url</key><value>jdbc:db2://server:50000/DATABASE2</value>
<key>hibernate.dialect</key><value>org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect</value>
<key>hibernate.default_schema</key><value>SCHEMA_NAME</value>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the DDL update is reflected in your Entity structure, its unlikely Hibernate would be able to do this.  Even if were possible, I'm guessing your DBA's won't like using Hibernate to manage the DB schema.  Create the DDL script and use that for environmental migrations, and have the DBA's run it under the appropriate account.

Comment: What sort of script would revoke DROP STATEMENT for a concrete user on all schemas of ALL DB2s? To revoke CREATE I've found this STAT: REVOKE CREATETAB ON DATABASE DB1 FROM USER1 BY ALL; ...but what kind of STAT does revoke DROP TABLEs? Could you get me some example? http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_grantandrevokecontrolaccess.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation for the DROP statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000945.html), you'll see that your ID must have either CONTROL authority on the table, DROPIN authority for the schema or higher-level privileges like DBADM or SYSADM.

So, as long as the user doesn't have these privileges, you're protected (even though, as @Aaron Sheffey states, it's unlikely that Hibernate would be executing DROP TABLE statements.).